# Cannot debug an anonymous function using node-inspector

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

Here is the simple demo server program that I am trying to step into using the node-inspector debugger:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.htm', 'utf8');
    var message = 'Hello world...';
    html = html.replace('{Message}', message);
    res.end(html);

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Try as I might, I cannot coax node-inspector to set a breakpoint (or alternatively, use the debugger statement) inside the passed anonymous function to the http.createServer(...) function call.  I can set a breakpoint on the first line (e.g., var http = require...) the second line, and the fourth line (http.createServer...), but NOT inside the passed anonymous function.

First I tried pulling out the anonymous function and created a function expression like so:

```
var callback = function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

and passed it to the

```
http.createServer(callback).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

That won't work either.

Finally, I tried naming the function like so:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function callback(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.htm', 'utf8');
    var message = 'Hello world...';
    html = html.replace('{Message}', message);
    res.end(html);
}

http.createServer(callback).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

And that works like a charm!

If this is an inherent limitation of node-inspector then that is a serious problem.  I am hoping that someone can show me an easier way to debug rather than have to pull out the anonymous functions and name them at global level?

Comment: does it work if you simply name the anon in place? (yeah, that's a thing)

Comment: No it doesn't.  I tried that already :)